# Bottomsheet wont hide completely on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Android Bottom sheet won't hide completely on some devices.
[image]

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bsheet_otp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottomsheet"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_login_otp_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The bottom sheet works well on some devices but on some devices, the bottom sheet is partially visible.

Answer (score 0):

try use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here make you bottom sheet a separate layout and include it inside this layout, not using a coordinate layout cause this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the parent view is coordinator layout I tried this code as well but causing the same problem.

Comment: so it should be this line : android:layout_height="wrap_content" in NestedScrollView, make it  android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: I think there is a problem with NestedScrollView, try using just a ScrollView and if not working still just remove the scrollview to see if the problem originated from this view.

Comment: hey, I had the same problem I just made the width of include zero. ow everything works fine